# Nextjs13 server component is running a fetch call twice on revalidate

Tags: next.js, next.js13

I have tried disabling reactStrictMode in next.config.js but it's not the problem. My code is just connecting to MongoDB and finding a user in the database and returning the user. Here is my component:

```
export const revalidate = 20;

async function getUsers() {
   const client = await clientPromise;
   const db = client.db("local");
   const data = await db
     .collection("users")
     .find({ email: "bob123@gmail.com" })
     .toArray();
   console.log("THIS IS THE SERVER RUNNING");
   return data;
}

export default async function Home() {
  const users = await getUsers();
  if (!users) return notFound();
  return (
    <main className={styles.main}>
      {users?.map((user) => (
        <p key={user._id}>{user.name}</p>
      ))}
    </main>
  );
}
```

Even in build mode, I still get my *console.log()* of **"THIS IS THE SERVER RUNNING**" printed out twice as you see below in the terminal. This happens every 20 seconds because of my revalidation setting.

[image]

My worry here is every 20 seconds I'm revalidating data twice, when it should only be once.

Anyone have any fix or explanation for this? Or could it possibly be a bug in Nextjs 13?

Comment: Can you share the `clientPromise` code ?